# How to split a string on all occurences of a character but the last one in python?

Tags: python, string, split

I am trying to iterate through rows of a dataset and split a list of strings from one of its columns. The split is done on the character ":".

The string always end with a redundant ":", so the split returns an empty string at the last index.

I am currently iterating through my results, removing the last empty item from each result.

**Is there an efficient way to split all but the last occurrence of the column without knowing how many occurrences of the split each string has?**

---

Example string looks like

```
 [abc:def:ghi:...:xyz:]
```

And I split it using the code:

```
answers = [exSheet.cell_value(r,6).split(':') for r in range(1, exSheet.nrows)]
```

Comment: You could `.rstrip(":")` to remove the trailing colon if present.

Comment: The expected result is `[abc, def, ghi, ..., xyz]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To return all split values, except for the last value, because it's empty in your case, you can return the split result list with index [0:-1]

You can find examples of list indices tricks here: [Useful List tricks in Python by RatulSaha](https://gist.github.com/RatulSaha/b41c52614da34762a74d16dc066b68df)

For example, lets say your data is

```
a='1:2:3:4:'
```

You can split it like this

```
a.split(':')
```

to get this:

```
Out[3]: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '']
```

or you can split it like this

```
a.split(':')[0:-1]
```

to get your wanted result

```
Out[4]: ['1', '2', '3', '4']
```